# Why won't some open applications come up on panel (Ubuntu Dock) icon click?

Tags: multiple-monitors, gnome-shell, window, ubuntu-dock, minimize

In an effort to regain some familiar Windows features, I've enabled [minimize on click](http://tipsonubuntu.com/2018/04/15/click-icon-minimize-application-window-ubuntu-18-04/), which works fairly well. I also have it set up to only show programs as open on the relevant monitor. However, in some circumstances, the running program won't come up on click. I resort to right-clicking, then clicking All Windows, then clicking the program icon. Obviously this is cumbersome.

Why won't the program come up upon clicking its panel (dock) icon?

UPDATE: I've learned that this occurs under the following conditions:

- I have multiple windows open for one program, such as Google Chrome
- One window is active on one monitor
- I minimize the window on another monitor and attempt to restore it

If a different program has focus, the window on the primary monitor comes back up as expected. It's only when the same program has focus on another monitor that Ubuntu ignores the dock icon click.

Comment: You have answered your question ;-) But I guess that there is another implicit question: How can I fix this problem? -- I don't know how to fix it, but I would try different versions of Ubuntu and also different desktop environments (so different flavours of Ubuntu (Kubuntu, Lubuntu ... Xubuntu). It is easy to try them live without installing.

Comment: Well, there are two definitions of "why", I suppose, but the important one has to do with whether there's a configuration setting I have wrong, or something else I can change.

Comment: Let us hope that someone who knows will see your question and write an answer :-) (Until then you could try different versions and flavours of Ubuntu.)